# Similarities between tcl and Python

Tags: python, tcl

Right now, I'm learning Python and Javascript, and someone recently suggested to me that I learn tcl. Being a relative noob to programming, I have no idea what tcl is, and if it is similar to Python. As i love python, I'm wondering how similar the two are so I can see if I want to start it.

Comment: It's similar in many ways. It's different in others. Unless you have a need to learn Tcl, why not just keep going with what you were doing and maybe learn an extra language later?

Comment: could you be more specific about the similarities?

Comment: Python and Tcl are both very high level imperative programming languages, just like JavaScript. You write statements that are executed one after the other unless interrupted by loops; there's no manual memory management and you generally work with objects rather than individual bytes.

Comment: Although I am a great fan of it, TCL is very weird. I certainly wouldn't recomend learning it early when you're just starting out programming. It may fill your head with odd ideas, or just confuse you.  Learn about python and javascript, and then maybe databases and networks, then come back and see what TCL is all about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl is not really very similar to Python. It has some surface similarities I guess, as it is a mostly procedural language, but its philosophy is rather different. Whereas Python takes the approach that everything is an object, Tcl's approach is sometimes described as "everything is (or can be) a string." There are some interesting things to learn from Tcl deriving from this approach, but it's one of the lesser-used languages, so maybe hold off until you have a tangible reason to use it. In any case, you have two very different languages on your plate already; no need (IMHO) to add a third just yet.

Comment: ok thanks a ton! I won't start it until i need it :)

Comment: "Everything is a string" hasn't _really_ been true for about 15 years; a more accurate description would be to say that every value is serializable and will be silently reinterpreted as necessary by the operations applied to it. The real take-home is that Tcl's type system is _very_ different to that of Python; I've seen a few people try to write common bytecode engines, but they've always failed due to the pervasive type-system differences.

Comment: I'll change that to "everything is (or can be) a string" then.  :-)

Answer (score 6):

You appear to be greatly confused about what should drive a person who count himself a programmer to learn another programming language: in fact, one should have a natural desire to learn *different* languages because only this can widen one's idea about how problems can be solved by programming (programming is about solving problems).  Knowing N similar programming languages basically gives you nothing besides an immediate ability to use those programming languages. This doesn't add anything to your mental toolbox.

I suggest you to at least look at functional languages (everyone's excited about them these days anyway), say, Haskell. Also maybe look at LISP or a similar thing.
Tcl is also quite interesting in its *concepts* (almost no syntax, everything is a string, uniformity of commands etc). Python is pretty boring in this respect--it's certainly enables a programmer to do certain things quick and efficient but it does not contain anything to satisfy a prying mind.

So my opinion is that your premises are wrong.